# The use of 'that' and the bare form of a verb

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

Can anyone help me with the use of 'that' and the bare form of a verb in the following sentence?

This plan suggested **that** the supply target for new and renewable energy **be** increased to 20% by 2020.

Here, I would like to know how the 'be' was used without expressing its tense. I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: It's the subjunctive mood, and this has to be a duplicate question. Americans still use it in situations like this; it's less prevalent in the U.K.

Comment: @RK01 Argh, that...be the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and for informing me of it as a duplicate. I wasn't even sure how to find similar questions and answers. Thank you!